# Rust compiler appears confused by Result type with anyhow

Tags: rust, anyhow

I'm trying to compile something like the following:

```rust
use anyhow::Result;
use std::sync::{mpsc, Mutex, OnceLock};
use std::cell::Cell;
use std::fmt;

static COMS: OnceLock<Mutex<Coms>> = OnceLock::new();

struct Coms {
    tx: Cell<Option<mpsc::Sender<Msg>>>,
    rx: Cell<Option<mpsc::Receiver<Msg>>>,
}

enum Msg {}

fn bar() -> Result<()> {
    let (tx, rx) = mpsc::channel();
    COMS.set(
        Mutex::new(
            Coms {
                tx: Cell::new(Some(tx)),
                rx: Cell::new(Some(rx)),
            }
        )
    );
    //)?;
    Ok(())
}

fn main() {
    let _ = bar();
}
```

I get an expected warning about an unused Result:

```
warning: unused `Result` that must be used
  --> src/main.rs:17:5
   |
17 | /     COMS.set(
18 | |         Mutex::new(
19 | |             Coms {
20 | |                 tx: Cell::new(Some(tx)),
...  |
23 | |         )
24 | |     );
   | |_____^
```

However, if I swap out the line with the `);` for a `)?;`, I get an error like:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `Mutex<Coms>: std::error::Error` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:25:6
   |
25 |     )?;
   |      ^ the trait `std::error::Error` is not implemented for `Mutex<Coms>`
   |
```

The [documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.OnceLock.html#method.set) for `OnceLock::set()` says it returns a `Result`, so why does it look like it is returning a `Mutex<Coms>` in the second case?

Why does rustc seem to think this is a `Result` in the first case (expected) and a `Mutex<Coms>` in the second case? This is using `rustc 1.71.0`. I must be misunderstanding what the compiler is trying to tell me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is a `Result`. Specifically, the [signature of that function](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.OnceLock.html#method.set) is

> ```
> pub fn set(&self, value: T) -> Result<(), T>
> ```

On success, we return `()`. On failure, we give ownership of the `T` back to the caller.

In your case, the return type is `Result<(), Mutex<Coms>>`.

Now, [`anyhow::Error`](https://docs.rs/anyhow/latest/anyhow/struct.Error.html) is a really neat type. It's capable of storing any error condition, but not *any* type. It can't store an `i32`, or a lot of other random types. It can only store types that implement [`Error`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/error/trait.Error.html), and `Mutex` does not implement that trait.

You can't convert a `Mutex<Coms>` into a `anyhow::Error`.

You can explicitly discard it if you don't care about the error condition.

```
let _ = COMS.set(...);
```

This is a loud assertion to Rust saying "Yes, we might get `Err`. I don't care; ignore it".

You can replace the `Mutex<Coms>` with an actual error type using [`map_err`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.map_err) and then use `?` on *that* to convert to `anyhow::Error`. You can panic on failed sets, using [`expect`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.expect).

Or, of course, you can just straight-up pattern match on the result and do something custom with the original mutex.

Comment: I'll add that `anyhow` provides easy creation of `anyhow::Error`s with the `anyhow!()` macro that take a formatting string (or an error to wrap).

Comment: In case `map_err()` is not obvious, it would be sometihng like `COMS.set(...).map_err(|_| anyhow::anyhow!("my poor Mutex got rejected and returned to me")?;`. It's very likely what the OP wants in this situation.

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate the explanation. I understand now that the `Result` from `OnceLock::set()` contains something other than a `Error` and, more generally, an `Err()` variant does not necessarily need to contain an `Error`. Thank you!